# Formula for Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, xls, xlsx, xlsm

Good day all. 
Have a headache worksheet.Plus I am something of a newbie at excel.
I have a sheet with varying ranges. Each value that is to be displayed, depends on a value entered in two other cells. For example:

```
Cell A14 = Item Description (drop down list)
Cell A18 = Item Weight
Cell C15 = Cost per Item (this varies depending on description & weight)
Cell D15 = Final calculated cost
```

In Cell C15, some items have anywhere from 3 to 6 different values/costs depending on the weight & description of the item being ordered. 
eg: 
One item range & cost:

```
1-44 = 1.52 per item
45-299 = 1.29 per item
300-499 = 1.25 per item
500-999 = 1.11 per item
1000- = 0.92 per item
```

While another costs:

```
1-44 = 13.02 per item
45-99 = 4.02 per item
100-299 = 3.87 per item
300-499 = 3.70 per item
500-  = 3.59 per item
```

Keeping in mind as well that there are 13 different items, how do I get cell C5 to show the corresponding value depending on the item description in cell A14 and item weight in cell A18 ? 
I have gotten as far as cell d5 where it can calculate based on the item description with a Vlookup formula:

```
=IF(A19*C15<VLOOKUP(A14,Sheet4!$B$1:$D$26,3,0),VLOOKUP(A14,Sheet4!$B$1:$D$26,3,0),A19*C15)
```

I have also created other sheets (1 & 4) that have the other other ranges.
Would this be an IF function, another VLookup or a combination of both?

Thanks in advance.

Seems I dont have enough reps to post an image.

Comment: can you please show a screenshot of your workbook? It's a little difficult to follow your example.

Comment: Seems I dont have enough reps to post an image.

Comment: Provide as link - anyone who has rep will edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sumproduct:

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Just set up your table with the max and min ranges and the correspoding amounts.

**ADDENDUM:**

Here is how you would do it with SUMIFS()

[image: Example 3]

[image: Example 4]

Comment: You could also probably use =sumifs() if you are more comfortable with that.

Comment: Thank you very much. After a few tweaks, the SUMPRODUCT solved everything. Thank you all and have a wonderfully blessed day